# Prolog logic query

Tags: prolog

There is a database that contains the following:

```
likes(mary,food).
likes(mary,wine).
likes(john,wine).
likes(john,mary).
```

is it possible to deduce from the above info whether " john likes everything that mary likes" using Prolog. If yes, how?

Comment: John does not like `food` but Mary does.

Comment: do you want to deduce `likes(john,X) :- likes(mary,X).` ?

Comment: Maybe `\+ (likes(mary, X), \+ likes(john, X)).` (there is no object X that Mary likes and John doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it's not that hard. One way would be to say the obvious:

```
mary_and_john_like_all_the_same_things :-
  setof( J , likes(john,J) , Likes ) ,
  setof( M , likes(mary,M) , Likes )
  .
```

Comment: You don't need the `Likes` argument to the `mary_and_john_like_all_the_same_things` predicate.

Comment: @lurker: true, if one has no interest in knowing the set of likes that the two of them have in common.